# Snmp Version 3 Getbulk OPeration in java language

Tags: java, response, snmp4j

I learned `Snmp version 3.i` to perform `Getbulk` Operation version in `Java`. But problem is that I've created two programs, one is Server and second is Agent. My Server sends the request for Agent and Agent get the request. It performs some operations and send the request for the server, but server is unable to receive the response.

Any help on above scenario.

Comment: please somebody help  the snmp version 3 in java GetBulk Agent Operation.